# Showing data from database in netbeans android

Tags: java, android, database, netbeans

First of all, I'm completely new to Android programming so bear with me.
I use Netbeans and would like to show on an emulated phone. Using instructions from the internet, I wrote this code accordingly:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{


    try {
    String host,uName,uPass;
    host="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Recipes [dico on DICO]";
    uName="admin";
    uPass="admin";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    String SQL = "select NAME from BREAKFAST";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
    rs.next( );
    String fName=rs.getString("NAME");
    System.out.println(fName);


    }
    catch(SQLException err){

       System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
```

The data doesn't appear to show up in the MainActivity window. But the text from the xml does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is your question (looks like you're trying to connect from Android to Derby which is bundled with Netbeans). Few suggestions:

-android doesn't support Derby natively, but you can use SQLite instead. See this arcticle how to use [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

-if you would like to connect to remote database, then you can probably use common Java libraries for that. Or better would be if you expose your DB via services (like REST for e.g.)

-use `android.util.Log` instead of System.out.println(). In your case you don't "print" anything to `MainActivity`, but with using `System.out.println()`, specified string is usually printed to logcat. With `Log.*` methods you have more control over tags,levels,...